# MYSQL query Alter table engine only if engine not innodb

Tags: mysql, if-statement, innodb, alter

I would like to run one query that alter table's engine (ALTER TABLE `table1` ENGINE = INNODB) only if the current engine is not INNODB.

How can I do that?

Update:
I got a case of a query trying to alter the table's engine while its already innodb.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE t ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

You can use this query. If db engine already InnoDB then nothing will happen.
Output will be

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)
```

if engine not in InnoDB, then it will convert to InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

The command has no effect if the table is already on `InnoDB`.

You can query the table engine from information_schema:

```
SELECT `ENGINE` from `information_schema`.`TABLES`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='my_schema' AND `TABLE_NAME`='table1';
```

Answer (score 0):

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#generating_alters provides several tips about converting from MyISAM to InnoDB, including:

To generate all the ALTERs to convert all the MyISAM tables to InnoDB:

```
SELECT  CONCAT('USE ', table_schema, ';  ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' ENGINE=InnoDB;')
    FROM  information_schema.tables
    WHERE  engine = 'MyISAM'
      AND  table_schema NOT IN ('mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema');
```

Then copy and paste the output into the mysql commandline tool.